# Disabling own event listener while it is executing

Tags: javascript, event-handling, event-listener

I have this cool typing effect on my site that executes when you press enter but I do not want users to be able to press enter again while the typing effect is executing.
This is what I am currently working with:

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        getResult(document.getElementById("input").value)
    }
});
```

I have tried removing the event listener within itself but then how would I add it back?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the typing effect duration, but lets assume it takes 400ms. So what you would want is called to `throttle` the function calls. This is nicely done by first generating a throttled version of the event handler.

This one is from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-throttling/

```js
const throttleFunction = (func, delay) => {
  let prev = 0;
  return (...args) => {
    let now = new Date().getTime();
    if (now - prev > delay) {
      prev = now;
      return func(...args);
    }
  }
}
```

Update: I will not be using it, but instead will use the very same idea inside the event handler, thus effectively "disconnecting" it from functioning.

```js
let prev = 0
let delay = 400
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    let now = new Date().getTime();
    if (now - prev > delay) {
      prev = now;
      getResult()
    } else {
      console.log("... wait ...")
    }
  }
});


function getResult() {
  console.log("registered");
}
```

```html
press [Enter] a few times, fast
```

Comment: This is really nice but the event I am starting by the event handler is different depending on what the user inputs and the calculation would be over my head. I do not want to throttle the listener but "disconnect it" for the duration of the event. Is it possible?

Comment: yeah my code isn't precise: it throttles any event, not just the [enter] but it's a valid idea. it's better to `return` out of the handler than to disconnect by `removeEventListener` and `addEventListener` again. i'll fix my code.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up making bool that is set to false and is true when you press enter for the first time. Then the bool is reset to the false state when the event is concluding. I do not think it is the most elegant option but it works nicely.

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter' && writing === false) {
        writing = true;
        getResult(document.getElementById("input").value);
        window.onkeydown = speedUp;
    }
});
```